# Which type of Charset suitable for image encoding ? [Kotlin]

Tags: arrays, android-studio, kotlin

I had tried to convert btye array to string in charset-8, but it's not working. Can someone guide me please.

Here is how I convert Bitmap to bytearray

```
private fun BitmapToByteArray(): ByteArray
    {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        btm1!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        val bitmapdata: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()
        return bitmapdata
    }
```

Here is how I encrypt the data

```
private fun encrypting_data(bitmapdata: ByteArray): String {
        val key = secretkey!!.text.toString()
        val btm1 = bitmapdata.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
        val s = btm1
        //generating key from given secret key
        val skey: Key = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), "AES")
        print(skey.toString())
        val c: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey)
        //encrypting text string
        val re = c.doFinal(s.toByteArray())

        //converting encrypted string to base64
        val re_base64 = Base64.encodeToString(re, Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.NO_PADDING)
        Log.e("aaAA", re_base64.toString())

        //converting each chr of base64 string to binary and combining it
        for (i in re_base64) {
            var single_b_string = Integer.toBinaryString((i.toInt()))
            //if binary str is less than 8 bit then making it 8 bit by adding 0's
            if (single_b_string.length < 8) {
                for (j in 1..(8 - single_b_string.length)) {
                    single_b_string = "0" + single_b_string
                }
            }
            //final binary string to hide in image
            b_string = b_string + single_b_string
        }
        Log.e("barraylength", b_string.toString())
        Log.e("barray", b_string!!.length.toString())
        return b_string.toString()

    }
```

please guide me, thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Charsets are mappings between characters and binary. It doesn't make sense to decode the bytes of an image into a string using a character encoding. There is even a chance that you find sequences of bytes that are not valid UTF-8 sequences, and will not be converted to characters correctly. Also, you're converting your bytearray into a string only to convert it back to a bytearray, why?

Comment: Also why are you converting the base64 representation into a binary string at the end of your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: none.

Charsets are used to map *characters* to binary and vice-versa. It doesn't make sense to decode the bytes of an image into a string using a character encoding. There is even a chance that you find sequences of bytes that are not valid sequences in the character encoding that you choose, so they will not be converted to characters correctly.

Sometimes it's necessary to use text to represent binary data (e.g. when using text-only transports/media to store it).
In these cases, you can use other kinds of encodings, for instance [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), but I guess you know about it because you're already sort of using base64 here as well.

Note that, in your current code, you are converting a `ByteArray` (`bitmapdata`) into a `String` (`btm1`/`s`) only to convert it back into a `ByteArray` (`s.toByteArray()`). Why do you even need to do so?

Comment: actually I am trying to convert an Image into bitmap, then from bitmap to byte array, so that I can encrypt it with AES. After i got the encrypted byte array, i will convert to base64. But i am not sure i am doing correct or not, can you teach me Sir, after i decode, i got the random "[B@9a7d34b"

Comment: This kind of string happens when you are trying to print to the console/logs an object that doesn't override the `toString()` method. You are effectively printing the object reference type `[B` (for byte array) and its address in memory. You can't really check the contents of byte arrays in the console anyway.

To encrypt the image, you could just directly use `bitmapdata` in `c.doFinal(bitmapdata)` (no need to convert it into a string first). The other part of your function depends on what you want to do with the result (keep the bytearray if you're ok with binary), base64 if you need text

Comment: Hi Sir, is there any way to contact you? I want to ask you about my coding?

Comment: @leafrain-Legit it's probably better if you post new precise questions on StackOverflow, because other people will be able to help as well. If you really want to chat, you can see some linked accounts on my SO profile (my email is available on GitHub).